# How to get extended data type in AX [X++]

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I am using the following code to get type of a field. How do I get "extended type"

```
tID = dict.tableName2Id('CustTable');
dt = new DictTable(tID);
if (dt)
{
    fId = dt.fieldName2Id('CustGroup');
    df = dt.fieldObject(fId);
    if (df)
    {
        t = df.type(); // Need to get extended data type
        print enum2str(t);
        pause;
    }

}
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `typeId()` instead of `type()` to get the ID of the extended data type. With `extendedTypeId2Name()` you can then find its name.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do "reflection" over the extended data types, then the correct Class is DictType:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg804354.aspx